# PhpStorm - Initialize fields for all methods (not only for __construct)

Tags: phpstorm

Is there way to make `Initialize fields` option available for `__construct()` params to be also available for other methods?

I have a lot of classes which has methods setting data which are not `__construct` and writing all class params and `$this->x = $x` is pain.

I don't need making getters & setters from fields. I need exact same behavior as for constructors. I have method `public function methodName($x, $y, $z)` and I want params to be created for class.

**Before**

```
public function notConstructor($x, $y, $z) {

}
```

**After**

```
private $x;

private $y;

private $z;

public function notConstructor($x, $y, $z) {
    $this->x = $x;
    $this->y = $y;
    $this->z = $z;
}
```

Comment: That pain should be a sign that the class is not well designed. A class that contains getters **and** setters is a sign that the code that should be in the class is somewhere else scattered through the code base.

Comment: It is easy to say that. In frameworks like Laravel you just do `new ClassX(params)` and if you need service in that class you just do `\App::make()` and you have it. SF4 with its new DI requires to inject everything in typehint. To achieve same thing you have 2 options. Require ALL services and data in constructor (this forces to typehint services in 2 places, controller & class) or make class as service where `construct` type hint required services and single method like `->populate(x,y,z)` receive the data.

Comment: This is why we use `setter` class for populating data and why I asked the question about field initialization for all methods:
https://jsfiddle.net/a5kodvr8/
This is most simple example, but there is the point. Maybe you have better solution. With regards.